# Is there any possibility to influence the lock screen gui

Tags: iphone, ios, lockscreen

I wonder if it's possible to create a GUI for the iPhone home screen when an app is used?

Since I guess the answer is no (it was in the past, havn't found anything new about iOS 7): if I have an audio player, would it be possible to kind of 'route' it to the homescreen like the Podcasts app does it? I have looked for answers but only came across jailbroken solutions so far.

Is there anything one can do there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe Apple allow this still, but it would be interesting to know if they have changed where they stand about this. I wouldn't get my hopes up though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the latest SDK (iOS 7.0) does not allow this, as in add custom GUI element to the lock screen. You can let the media player controls interact with your app if you are playing audio in the background.

And use the [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display track, artist name and cover art on the lockscreen.

Comment: Thanks. But them I'm bound to the Media Player and can't use Core Foundation to play my media right?

Comment: No you are not, `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` is available to all and so is detecting the media keys (both on the lockscreen, command center and headphones).

Comment: But what about displaying an image??Is that an impossible task?

Comment: No a image you can easily set. But be aware using this API for anything other then displaying song information will get you app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow any app to configure the Lock Screen in any way. You could have a music app which might display track details using the : `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`.

Other than that all you can display is Notifications.

This isn't available on any version of iOS.